# Reformulating a quadratic program suitable for R

Tags: r

My problem is one which should be quite common in statistical inference:

min{(P - k)'S(P - k)} subject to k >= 0

So my choice variable is `k`, a 3x1 vector. The 3x1 vector `P` and 3x3 matrix `S` are known. Is it possible to reformulate this problem so I can use `R`'s `solve.QP` quadratic programming solver? This solver requires the problem to be in the form

min{-d'b + 0.5 b' D b} subject to A'b >= b_0.

So here the choice vector is is `b`. Is there a way I can make my problem fit into `solve.QP`? Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: Yes, solve for `b` defined as `P - k`. `k > 0` can be translated to `-b >= -P`. So set `D` to `S`, `d` to 0, `A` to minus identity and `b_0` to `P`. Once you have found the optimal `b`, your optimal `k` is `P - b`.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was very helpful indeed. I thought about translating that constraint but I didn't think of including the negative sign.